# Issues related to socket and HTTP connections in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, http, sockets, networking

I'm developing a Flutter app that interacts with a Wi-Fi chipset.Firstly, this microcontroller needs to enable a Wi-Fi hotspot, and then the app actively connects to this Wi-Fi hotspot.Second the app is connected to the microcontroller's hotspot, I need to create a socket client in the app to send messages to the microcontroller.When I receive the information from the microcontroller, I close the socket.But the issue arises when, after I've finished using the socket, all network connections in my app become unavailable.Below is my main code:

```
//pubspec.yaml
  #wifi
  network_info_plus: ^4.0.2
  wifi_iot: ^0.3.18
  wifi_scan: ^0.4.0+1
  flutter_iot_wifi: ^0.0.3
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.2
```

```
void _connectWifi(String ssid, String password, callback) async { 
  if (!await WiFiForIoTPlugin.isEnabled()) {  
    await WiFiForIoTPlugin.setEnabled(true);
  }

  FlutterIotWifi.connect(ssid, password, prefix: false);

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 8));
  String? wifi = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.getSSID();
  print(wifi);
  if (wifi == 'duoqin_zjm') { //my wifi ssid
    callback(true);   
  } else {
    callback(false);
  }
 
}
```

```
Future<Socket?> TcpClient(String ip, String port) async {
  Socket? socket;
  try {   
    socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.10.254', 60200);
    print('Connected to server: ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Socket Error: $e');
    if (socket != null) {
      await socket.close();
    }
    socket = null;
  }
  return socket;
}
```

```
 ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      print('$wifi,$_ssid,$Password');

      _connectWifi(_ap_ssid!, _ap_pwd!,
          (res) async {
        if (res) {
          print('==========>>>$res');

          _socket ??= await TcpClient(
              '192.168.10.254', '60200');

          Map<String, dynamic> confignet = {
            'ssid': _ssid,
            'pwd': Password,
          };
        
          _socket?.write(jsonEncode(confignet));
          //
          if (_socket != null) {
            _sockStrem = _socket?.listen(
                (event) => sockListenCb(event),
                // onDone: () => _socket?.destroy(),
                onError: errorHandler,
                cancelOnError: false);
          }
        }
      });
    },
```

```
void sockListenCb(event) async {
  String data = String.fromCharCodes(event);
  print(data); //get my need ,it's true
  print('----------->>>>');

  if (_socket != null) {
    try {
      await _socket?.close();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      _socket = null;
      print('回调销毁socket =>$_socket');
    } catch (e) {
      print('销毁socket出错: $e');
      _socket?.destroy();
      _socket = null;
    }
  }
    await await FlutterIotWifi.disconnect();
```

```
when I run in await FlutterIotWifi.disconnect(); 
my wifi it's was dissconnect,and connect my normal wifi,But afterwards, the network connections for my entire app encounter errors.
```

```
This is the log from the error that occurred during the listen event:
SocketException: 
SocketException: Software caused connection abort (OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103), address = 192.168.10.254, port = 40566
```

Because I need to use HTTP after disconnecting the socket connection.
But the HTTP error is reporting a socket-related issue.

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Machine is not on the network, errno = 64), address = qdevice.duoqin.com, port = 443, uri=https:/device/action?culture=en-US
```

I think the socket connection is causing issues with the HTTP protocol and the entire network because before using the socket, everything was functioning normally, and HTTP requests were going through without any problems.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue and can provide some insight?
This is the HTTP error image captured in Flutter DevTools:[image]

[image][image]

One image shows a successful connection, and the other shows an error in the connection.

Comment: I still haven't tried anything like this in Dart. Is it possible that when you try to create the HTTP request, the connection is not yet set, meaning you aren't  yet connected to the network?
Try to create a method that tracks what is the machine connection status, (if it has a local network IP) before calling the HTTP request. 
Another possible origin of the error is that after you destroy the socket connection,  your socket Methods / Widgets are still active ( or are called), which generates the connection error because the socket is null at that point.

Comment: I don't setting the socket to null after destroying,but http still error,
I can assure you that the network I'm connecting to is functioning properly.The network issues are occurring only with this Flutter app.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my point. 
I don't think it is a network error, but an event management error, maybe caused by how the socket connection is terminated. I can be wrong, but that's what I believe it's the most probable cause for the error. Make some tests to make sure the socket is well-defined and you have an IP when doing another HTTP request.

Comment: I've resolved the error, but I'm not sure why it occurred. When I disconnect the socket, the Wi-Fi automatically reconnects to the normal network and that will be error,but as soon as I use code to navigate to the settings page and tap on the saved Wi-Fi, the network becomes functional again.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the solution below?

###### For Android:

- In `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest ...other params...>
   // STEP: 1 make sure you have INTERNET permission
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> <-- STEP: 2 add this line
        <activity
    </application>
</manifest>
```

###### For iOS

- In `ios/Runner/Info.plist`

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Still failde,It's still the same as before.